# User(Android device) is not showing up in OneSignal Dashboard.OneSignal AppId format is invalid reactnative

Tags: onesignal

I am using OneSignal for push notification in reactnative.

> Blockquote
>   My problem here is 'User' (my android device) is not showing up in OneSignal Dashboard because my user isn't subscribed.
>   Blockquote
>     I have followed the instructions as in the docs but couldn't subscribe user. After debugging app , logcat says -
>       dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging', referenced from method com.onesignal.OSUtils.hasGCMLibrary

```
OneSignal AppId format is invalid.
Example: 'b2f7f966-d8cc-11e4-bed1-df8f05be55ba'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID:



    ****here is my app/build.gradle****

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.onesignalexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: "1b67a245-829d-4275-846c-118fce78eba3",
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
     compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
}


task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

    **Here is my AndroidManifest.xml** 
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.onesignalexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>

Anyone help appreciated
```